# I want to be able to edit data given in my foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

On my site I'm building my own kind of blog for the users and would like for the comments that people place under the posts to be editable. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get this far with it. Because they all have the same class/id.

I've tried using data-id, but I'm not really adept when it comes to those. Other than that I've searched for ages, but couldn't really find anything that could help me with the code I have.

Function that gets the post and comments:

```
    public function announcement(Announcement $announcement)
    {
        $announcements = Announcement::findOrFail($announcement->id);

        $category_lists = Category::withCount('posts')->get();
        $replies = Reply::where('post_id', $announcement->id)->paginate(5);
        return view('announcements.details', compact('announcements', 'category_lists', 'replies'));
    }
```

The comment foreach:

```
                    @foreach($replies as $reply)
                        <div class="announcement">
                            @if(Auth::user()->admin == 1 || Auth::user()->id == $reply->user_id)
                                <a href="/reactie/destroy/{{$reply->id}}" class="float-right"><i class="fal fa-dumpster"></i></a>
                            @endif
                            @if(Auth::user()->id == $reply->user_id)
                            <i class="fal fa-pencil float-right" id="yeet" class="float-right showhidereply" style="color: #007ac3; margin-right: 10px;" data-id="{{ $reply->id }}"></i>
                            @endif
                            <p style="font-size: 0.8rem;">{{$reply->created_at->diffForHumans()}} | Geplaatst door <span>{{$reply->username}}</span></p>
                            <p style="margin-top: -10px;">{!! $reply->post_content !!}</p>
                            @if(Auth::user()->id == $reply->user_id)
                            <div class="reply-expand-{{$reply->id}}" style="display: none;">
                                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('Reply Edit', ['id' => $reply->id]) }}">
                                    @csrf
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <strong>Reactie Aanpassen:</strong>
                                            <textarea class="form-control summernote" name="detail">{!! $reply->post_content !!}</textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="border-radius: 0px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px -4px #000000;">Aanpassen</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            @endif
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Editting function:

```
    public function postSummernoteeditorReply(Request $request, $id){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'detail' => 'required',
        ]);

        $detail=$request->detail;
        $dom = new \DomDocument();
        $dom->loadHtml( mb_convert_encoding($detail, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

        foreach($images as $img){
            $src = $img->getAttribute('src');

            // if the img source is 'data-url'
            if(preg_match('/data:image/', $src)){

                // get the mimetype
                preg_match('/data:image\/(?<mime>.*?)\;/', $src, $groups);
                $mimetype = $groups['mime'];

                // Generating a random filename
                $filename = uniqid();
                $filepath = "/img/blog/$filename.$mimetype";

                // @see http://image.intervention.io/api/
                $image = Image::make($src)
                    // resize if required
                    /* ->resize(300, 200) */
                    ->encode($mimetype, 100)    // encode file to the specified mimetype
                    ->save(public_path($filepath));

                $new_src = asset($filepath);
                $img->removeAttribute('src');
                $img->setAttribute('src', $new_src);

            } // <!--endif
        } // <!--endforeach

        $detail = $dom->saveHTML();
        $summernote = Summernote::find($id);
        $summernote->post_content = $detail;
        //dd($summernote->post_content);
        //dd($summernote->post_id);
        $summernote->update();

        return redirect(url()->previous());
}
```

JQuery to show the editting form:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.summernote').summernote({
                height: 400,
            });
            $('#yeet').click(function() {
                $('.reply-expand').toggle("slide");
            });

            // change the selector to use a class
            $("#yeet").click(function(){
                // this will query for the clicked toggle
                var $toggle = $(this);

                // build the target form id
                var id = "#replycomment-" + $toggle.data('id');

                $( id ).toggle('slide');
            });

        });
```

The expected outcome should be to be able to edit each comment individually by clicking on the edit icon(pencil) next to the comment and having the form show before being able to edit. I already have the edit function and displaying the form working, but only for the first comment.

I hope someone will be able to help! Many thanks!

EDIT: When I click the edit button on the first comment, it opens the form with the data of the second/last comment, but clicking the second/last edit button doesn't do anything.

[image: Comment Section]

Answer (score 0):

First have a unique Id for the clickable items. Right now they all have the same id (yeet) and that could be the cause of the problem.

```
<i class="fal fa-pencil float-right yeet" id="yeet-{{ $reply->id }}" class="float-right showhidereply" style="color: #007ac3; margin-right: 10px;"></i>
```

We can keep yeet as a class to handle the click events for all the comments. This way each comment will have a different Id and they will all go through the same click event.

Now change the selectors to use the yeet class intead of the id.

```
$('.yeet').click(function() {
    //get the clicked element id and toggle the respective form
}
```

You have to add unique ids to the form in the same way as before to be able to toggle each one independently.

Comment: @SpookyCode The yeet id is not unique, all edit buttons will have the same id and that could be causing some problems. Try adding the reply->id to it. Something like yeet-{{$reply->id}}

Comment: How do I use this in the JQuery code? Sorry for my novice questions hehe, I'm not really that great in front-end